# How to get domain name form subdomain dinamically htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess that is working:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I have 4 domains that point to the same server (domain.com)

```
example1.com
example2.com
example3.com
example4.com
```

Right now with the actual htaccess when i go to

```
test.example1.com
```

It will show the files from the directory

```
domain.com/test
```

Just how i want it.

But i need to implement a new feature.

So when i go to

```
test.example1.com
```

It needs to go to

```
domain.com/example1.com/test
```

and the same goes to

```
test2.example1.com ---->  domain.com/example1.com/test2
test5.example2.com ---->  domain.com/example2.com/test5
test6.example3.com ---->  domain.com/example3.com/test6
test9.example4.com ---->  domain.com/example4.com/test9
```

IT DOES NOT REDIRECT, it rewrites, i don't want it to redirect.

Comment: `IT DOES NOT REDIRECT, it rewrites, i don't want it to redirect` can you clarify this statement?

Comment: of course, let's say i visit test2.example1.com, it should not redirect to domain.com/example1.com/test2, it should just show the content with out redirecting

Comment: You have too many examples. you have multiple domains with multiple subdomains that you want to rewrite to a main domain as a subfolder?

Comment: yes is basicly that, so you can have an idea of what is about, think of it as a wordpress, each subdomain is a folder, but i have multiple domains, so each domains needs a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your existing rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```